# Is a compacthypersurface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a "conformally compact Einstein manifold"?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

If $S$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (like a sphere) then is $S$ a "conformally compact Einstein manifold"?

It's a compact manifold. According to the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_geometry#Conformal_manifolds), it is a conformal manifold if it is equipped with an equivalence class in which two metrics $g$ and $h$ are equivalent iff $h=\lambda^2 g$ for $\lambda:S \to \mathbb{R}$ smooth.

An [Einstein manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_manifold) I find difficult to understand since I don't understand Ricci  tensors.

Comment: Maybe vacuously: Conformal compactness of a metric refers to the existence of a conformal structure on the boundary of $S$ that is suitably compact with the behavior of the metric as one approaches the boundary. A sphere, on the other hand, has no boundary.

Comment: If S is 2-dimensional, it's metric is conformal to Einstein one. In dimensions more than 2, this is false.